# Recargar componente al hacer login

Tags: angular

Tengo un avatar con un ngif si el usuario no está loggeado no se muestra el avatar, si el usuario está loggeado se muestra el avatar. Mi problema es que cuando inicio sesión en mi `login.component.html` me lleva al /home `home.component` y el avatar lo tengo en el `app.component` entonces tengo que recargar la página para que se me actualice el avatar.

Como podría recargar el componente del app.component para que me muestre el avatar cuando inicie sesión?

Mi código es el siguiente:

Yo tengo mi `app.component.html`

```
    <div id="avatar-collapse" class="avatar-sidebar">
      <img *ngIf="!usserLogged" src="assets/images/user.png" />
      <img *ngIf="usserLogged && usserLogged.avatar == ''" src="assets/images/user.png" />
      <img *ngIf="usserLogged && usserLogged.avatar != ''" src="{{url_uploads_avatar}}{{usserLogged.avatar}}" />
    </div>
```

Aquí le digo que si el usuario no esté loggeado me muestre un avatar, que si el usuario está loggeado y el campo avatar de la base de datos está vacío muestre otro avatar y si el usuario está loggeado y tiene avatar pues que muestre dicho avatar.

Para obtener que el usuario está loggeado en mi `app.component.ts` tengo lo siguiente:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.usserLogged = this._userService.getUserLoggedIn();
  }
```

Finalmente en el servicio de mi usuario retorno en un json si hay algún usuario guardado en la caché. Este sería mi `user.service`

```
  getUserLoggedIn() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }
```

Finalmente tengo otro componente que se llama `login.component.html` que es el encargado de hacer el login, supongo que es en este cuando le doy al botón de iniciar sesión cuando debo recargar el app.component.html para que vuelva a consultar si hay alguna información en la caché.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa un servicio en el root, subscríbete y emite desde un `Subject` el valor del usuario o cuando hay un cambio con este.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
    public onLoginChange = new Subject();
}
```

Luego en tu componente App usas `OnInit` para observar los cambios y `OnDestroy` para de-suscribirte.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private componentDestroyed = new Subject();
    usserLogged: any;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.updateAvatar();
        this.loginService.onLoginChange.pipe(
            tap(() => this.updateAvatar()),
            takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed)
        ).subscribe();
    }

    updateAvatar() {
        this.usserLogged = this._userService.getUserLoggedIn();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.componentDestroyed.next();
        this.componentDestroyed.complete();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hola! @devconcept muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, edite el post de nuevo por que no sabría aplicar tu explicación a ver si pudieses hecharme una mano

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín Si miras mi respuesta hay una parte que dice que el valor del usuario debes emitirlo *cuando hay un cambio*. En tu pregunta no dices nada de como obtienes el usuario en primer lugar que usualmente es cuando te autenticas. El localStorage es sólo para persistirlo. Edité la respuesta para usar el valor inicial del usuario. En teoría el servicio de autenticación debe contener el `Subject` que emite el cambio y debes obtener el valor inicial del localStorage y actualizarlo cuando hay un login en la aplicación.

Comment: No entiendo cuando me dices que emita desde el ``subject`` el valor del usuario, se supone que ``public onLoginChange = new Subject();`` onLoginChange está vacío no?

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín Un `Subject` emite valores usando [`next`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject#next). Todos los que se hayan [suscrito](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable#subscribe) a el recibirán un callback con el valor. Así es como comunicas entre servicios, componentes y ambos. Desde el servicio de autenticación (o el `LoginService` en mi ejemplo) invocas `next(user)` y el componente app que está escuchando recibe el valor y sabe que debe actualizarlo. Eso es básicamente lo que hace el ejemplo.

Comment: Vale, yo puse el subject en el ``user.service.ts``, ya que hay es donde tengo la función donde recupero del ``localstorage`` el usuario y luego en el app.component.ts escucho lo que manda el user.service.ts para ver si cambia, es así?

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín El user service te da lo que está en el localStorage pero quien puso ese valor ahí luego de que flujo? En algún momento tuviste que autenticarte y salvar el valor en el localStorage. Justo cuando te autenticas debes notificar que hubo un cambio de usuario. Como organizas tus servicios ya es cosa tuya.

Comment: ``setUserLoggedIn(user: User) {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
    this.usserLogged = user;
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    console.log(localStorage);
  }`` supongo que refieres a eso no?

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín Exacto. Solo te falta una linea con `this.onLoginChanged.next(user)`. Debes tener el subject viviendo en este mismo servicio por supuesto.

Comment: Eso lo pongo en el ngOnInit de mi app.component pero me tira error

Comment: Listo, lo solucioné, muchas muchas gracias por tu paciencia muchísimas gracias!!